# Метод Update() создает новую запись вместо обновления текущей

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, razor

Я изучаю платформу .Net  и пытаюсь сделать небольшое CRUD-приложение с использованием AspNet 2.1. Когда я пытаюсь обновить запись с помощью метода Edit(), в БД создается новый объект вместо обновления текущего. Как это можно исправить?

Мои классы моделей:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
public class Company
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

Мой класс ViewModel для отображения двух моделей в представлении:

```
public class CustomViewModel
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public List<Company> Companies { set; get; }
}
```

Мои post/get методы для редактирования:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
{
    var cmView = new CustomViewModel
    {
        Employee = repo.Employees.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == id),
        Companies = repo.Companies.ToList()
    };
    return View(cmView);
}

[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(Employee employee)
{
    repo.Employees.Update(employee);
    repo.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

И форма в представлении:

```
@model CrudApp.ViewModels.CustomViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit employee";
}
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Home" asp-route-id="@Model.Employee.Id" >
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Employee.Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="Employee.Name" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Employee.Age" class="control-label">Age</label>
        <input type="number" asp-for="Employee.Age" class="form-control" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Employee.CompanyId">Company</label>
        <select asp-for="Employee.CompanyId" class="form-control" asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.Companies,"Id","Name"))"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: А с каким Id (первичным ключом) создается новый объект?

Comment: Id нового объекта на единицу больше последнего объекта в таблице.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что значения неиспользуемых в форме полей возвращаются обратно пустыми (`0` или `null`). Поэтому `Id` равен нулю. Очевидно, в БД нет работника с таким идентификатором, в результате чего создаётся новый.

Чтобы устранить это, можно добавить скрытое поле:

```
<input asp-for="Employee.Id" type="hidden" />
```

Возможно, кто-то предложит другое решение. Но раз никто больше не отвечает, то пусть будет так.

Comment: Благодарю за верный ответ.